# JPA : Foreign key not getting inserted in child class with @IdClass in both parent and child classes

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a parent with composite PK (id + serial_no).
The child also has a PK (id + serial_no + attribute), where FK is (id + serial_no)

Note : I have used @IdClass instead of @EmbeddedId, as in my **Parent** I have **id** to be generated from a sequence (And I read on stackoverflow that sequencegenerator doesn't work with embeddedid).

Problem :

```
Caused by: oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("schema_name"."child"."id")
```

Below is my save logic

```
Parent parent = new Parent();
parent.setSerialNo(0L);
//Note I don't want to set the Id as its supposed to be generated by the sequence

Child child = new Child();
child.setAttribute("abc");
//so in the below line am setting parent in child class
child.setParent(parent);
//note in the child am not setting the id and serial_no coz i want it to come from parent

repository.save(parent);
// I am expecting the cascade so that both the parent and child get saved
```

Below is my entity code :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
@IdClass(ParentPK.class)
public class Parent implements Serializable {
     @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator", sequenceName="o_seq", allocationSize=1)
    private Long id;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="serial_no")
    Long serialNo; 

     @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Child> childs;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="child")
@IdClass(ChildPK.class)
public class Child implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    Long id;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="serial_no")
    Long serialNo;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="attribute")
    String attribute;

    @JoinColumns(value = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "serial_no", referencedColumnName = "serial_no", insertable = false, updatable = false)
        })
    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=true)
    private Parent parent;
}
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="child")
@IdClass(ChildPK.class)
public class Child implements Serializable{
  
    @Id
    @Column(name="attribute")
    String attribute;

    @Id
    @JoinColumns(value = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "serial_no", referencedColumnName = "serial_no", insertable = false, updatable = false)
        })
    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=true)
    private Parent parent;
}

class ChildPK implements Serializable {

  Parent parent;
  String attribute;
  ...
}
```

See the Hibernate ORM documentation about [composite identifiers](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-composite-nonaggregated) for more details.